# wrap divs around one and stop divs from hiding away

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a situation as demonstrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BDb5K/56/), Ideally I want all the divs in the '#menu' div to wrap around the green div like this [image] 
but I understand that this would be hard to achieve so not too set on it. However, I want to be able to hover over the green div and the blue divs should appear and STAY there for the user to be able to click them. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: is absolute positioning aloud or are you avoiding it for some reason? seems a ul/li set up with block display and absolute positions should make this easy. A little padding on them all would fix the hovering issue when you move form green to blue. If that sounds good i can mock up an example real quick.

Comment: a lot of what you said went over my hide lol but sure, please provide an example if possible. Basically, I have a whole grid of these green divs and the '#menu' div may contain an unknown number of divs so manually positioning them might not be an option so like I said, I am ok with it not wrapped around as the number of blue divs changes and this makes it hard...

Answer (score 2):

Here you go [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lupos/4T8cT/)

Works basically like a suckerfish menu but with the squares positioned around with absolute. They will stay relative to the middle square so you can put it where ever you want. The inner div is there because the LI(blue boxes) have to touch the green one for the hover issue so the divs have the margin to create the appearance of space between them.

Comment: Just as an FYI you can make the ul/li into nested divs and achieve the same affect but if its an interface or menu of some kind you want the ul/li for seo purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use delay for this action. For example for `mouseleave` on green square. You should delay for 300ms and looking for `mouseenter` on blue divs. If this happens - break out the hide() effect for this/other blue divs.

Use `setTimeout()` function with the label for actions that I have discribed above.

Comment: makes sense but can you please edit the jsfiddle to show an example if possible please...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BDb5K/61/ that is what I got so far with the timeout function but how do I break out of the .hide() function? because as of now they still disappear after 1 sec, surely I can increase that time but I don't want them to still stay there if the cursor is not on them...

Comment: Here is your code: http://jsbin.com/ehayev/2/edit#source. I have use jQuery plugin `jQuery timers` - it's an abstraction for native javascript functions. It's more convenient for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can them appear "around". You'll just have to decide what this means in terms of HTML.  One example would be: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BDb5K/69/)

```
$('.boxGroup').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.blueBox').show();
},function(){
    $(this).find('.blueBox').hide();
});
```

...

```
<table class="boxGroup">
    <tr>
        <td class="boxColumn">
            <div class="box blueBox"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="boxColumn">
            <div class="box blueBox"></div>
            <div class="box greenBox"></div>
            <div class="box blueBox"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="boxColumn">
            <div class="box blueBox"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And before everyone freaks out "omg tables". Vertical align is not something browsers handle well without js or table abuse.

*ps: please don't use delays unless you require this functionality. All hover menus are built with "containers" as the trigger. Everything (including the hidden objects) live inside the container, then all you have to do is reveal and hide the contents; blue boxes will count just like green ones as hovers so everything stays visible.